# Add Div without changing position of other html elements

Tags: html, css, position

I have a div that once I add in the code, moves a table element down with it. I am soon going to make this div slide able but I can not do it yet because if I do, once the div slides in then the table will move down. I put all the code in a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vjf2665m/) so you can see all of it but I'll put the basic code below.

HTML:

```
<div id='fullPurchArea'>
<div>
<div id='checkbook'>
    <table id='tablecheck' cellspacing='0' ; cellpadding='0'>
      <th id='tableheader'>Check Book</th>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th class='cats'>Item</th>
          <th class='cats'>Cost</th>
          <th class='cats'>Balance</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id='tr1'>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='tr2'>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='tr3'>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#fullPurchArea {
  background-color: #D64040;
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  position:relative;
  left:468px;
}
#tablecheck {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 290px;
  left: 980px;
  line-height: 10px;
  background-color: #8FF2E5;
  cellspacing: 0;
  cellpadding: 0;
  height: 240px;
}

.cats {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px gray;
}

#tableheader {
  color: #2AB5A2;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #46F271;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  left: 70px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#tr1,
#tr3 {
  background-color: #D6D6D6;
}

#tr2 {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

I don't know if the problem is in the code I posted so I recommend checking out the JSfiddle.

EDIT: To clarify whenever I add the div with the id 'fullPurchArea' to the code the table with the id 'tablecheck' gets re-positioned.

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit? What div are you trying to add? Where are you trying to place it? Can show the code for the div?

Comment: It seems that you need `position: absolute` but as said above, it's not clear.

Comment: I think you're referring to the empty slider div? I took that out and except for that div disappearing I saw no change to the position of any other elements. Adding content to it doesn't change anything either.

Comment: html error there, it's missing a `</div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Since CSS3, we have 2 ways of making moving elements without disturbing layout, first :

```
position: absolute;
top/left/bottom/right: 10px;
```

Now, you can use a more simple way to move with **CSS3** and `transform: translate()`

```
transform: translate(x, y);
```

Or 3D version

```
transform: translate3d(x, y, z);
```

Be sur to add the prefix that you need (-webkit-, -moz-, -ms-), check here for [2D](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform) and here for [3D](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d)

Using transform  allows you to move element without affecting the layout nor making your element losing his space like `position: absolute;`.